# Replace words except matched to dot

Tags: awk

File

```
TxA1000| Tx5000| TxAc2000  
Ms67Ty| AtX0000| Tx5000
```

Required Output:

```
.Tx5000.
..Tx5000
```

Tried Solution:

```
awk -F '|' '!/Tx5000/{next}{gsub(/[aA0-zZ9]/, ".")}1 file
```

Obtained output:

```
.......| ......| ........
......| .......| ......
```

Plese needed help.

Comment: Your pattern in the gsub is (almost certainly) wrong. It should be a list of ranges [a-zA-Z0-9]. You get all the dots because you include a wide range 0-z. Also, you obviously expect it to loop over fields, but it works on whole lines unless you write the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
awk -F '[|] ' -v OFS="" -v ok="Tx5000" '
   {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != ok) $i="."; print}
' <<END
TxA1000| Tx5000| TxAc2000
Ms67Ty| AtX0000| Tx5000
END
```

```
.Tx5000.
..Tx5000
```

Your field separator appears to be "pipe+space", so the `-F` argument is more specific.

---

You'll have to be more specific with your "doesn't work with a file" claim:

```bsh
$ cat >|file
TxA1000| Tx5000| TxAc2000
Ms67Ty| AtX0000| Tx5000

$ awk -F '[|] ' -v OFS="" -v ok="Tx5000" '
   {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != ok) $i="."; print}
' file
.Tx5000.
..Tx5000
```

Same results with `awk '...' < file` and `cat file | awk '...'`

Comment: ... may I recommend that you formulate your `awk` command to be used on a file (like in the OPs example) instead of feeding a here-doc? Not everyone will be familiar with that construct.

Comment: Well then, a good opportunity for them to learn it.

Comment: The advantage of using << for answers is that it proves your results came from that data, rather than believing a redirection and a separate cat of the file. It would be helpful if OPs did the same on occasion, too.

Comment: It worked only for heredoc but not with file. With file or stdin through pipe it was substituting all letters with dot and not words

Comment: I need more information.

Comment: results were same but all on single line. Output was like .Tx5000..Tx5000.two lines were getting merge

Comment: I suspect that's an issue with your input file. What line endings does it have?

Comment: Yes i noticed that the ending also has a pipe and so one extra field is counted

Comment: Take care to use `-v OFS=""` and not `-v ORS=""`

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
l=re.compile(r'Tx5000')
k=open('rr.txt','r')
for i in k:
    if re.search(l,i):
        o=i.strip().split("|")
        
        for w in range(0,len(o),1):
            we=[]
            if (o[w].strip() == "Tx5000"):
                
                for q in range(0,len(o),1):
                    if (q == w):
                        we.append("Tx5000")
                    else:
                        we.append(".")
            print "".join(we).strip()
```

output

```
.Tx5000.
..Tx5000
```